# Error converting from varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run this update statement, however, I getting an error that reads 'Error converting varchar to numric'.  Data types of the fields are as follows:

```
dbo.keyona.customer_id_num is a decimal(16,0)
s.customer_identifier is varchar(250)
s.customer_cis is varchar(250)
k.dedupe_static is decimal(20,0
```

)

Query is as follows

```
update dbo.keyona
set dbo.keyona.customer_id_num = s.customer_identifier
from dbo.keyona k join [StorageDB - BAW].[dbo].[MI_NedLife_Mapper_Embedded_Linked_201804] s
on  s.customer_cis = k.dedupe_static
```

Comment: And the data? :) We can't run your query, we don't have access to your SQL Server.  [Forum Etiquette: How to post data for a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I d not have rights to share the data :( was hoping that you could help me with the syntax

Comment: If you need to cast.your join columns, then your table has a design problem.  You should fix your tables first before using any help you get here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--Please try like below- Your data types should be same. I think your should fix that first. If you cannot pls try below-

```
update dbo.keyona
set dbo.keyona.customer_id_num = CASE WHEN TRY_PARSE(s.customer_identifier as decimal(16,0)) IS NOT NULL THEN 
                                CAST(s.customer_identifier as decimal(16,0))
                                ELSE 
                                    dbo.keyona.customer_id_num
                                END
from dbo.keyona k join [StorageDB - BAW].[dbo].[MI_NedLife_Mapper_Embedded_Linked_201804] s
on  CAST(s.customer_cis as VARCHAR(500)) = CAST(k.dedupe_static as VARCHAR(500))
```

**--Much better solution will be-**

```
update dbo.keyona
set dbo.keyona.customer_id_num = CAST(s.customer_identifier as decimal(16,0))                               
from dbo.keyona k join [StorageDB - BAW].[dbo].[MI_NedLife_Mapper_Embedded_Linked_201804] s
on  CAST(s.customer_cis as VARCHAR(500)) = CAST(k.dedupe_static as VARCHAR(500))
WHERE TRY_PARSE(s.customer_identifier as decimal(16,0)) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: It would be better to filter them in the `WHERE` in this case, as it might update rows with their same value (and possible fire triggers in vain).

Comment: Thank you very much! the second code works perfectly

Comment: Welcome. Glad to help as always :)

Answer (score 2):

Identify records that can't be correctly converted with:

```
SELECT
    s.customer_identifier
from 
    dbo.keyona k 
    join [StorageDB - BAW].[dbo].[MI_NedLife_Mapper_Embedded_Linked_201804] s on  s.customer_cis = k.dedupe_static
WHERE
    TRY_PARSE(s.customer_identifier AS decimal(16,0)) IS NULL
```

Then you will have to either filter them, or fix them so they can be converted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
update dbo.keyona
set dbo.keyona.customer_id_num = CAST(s.customer_identifier as decimal(16,0))                               
from dbo.keyona k join [StorageDB - BAW].[dbo].[MI_NedLife_Mapper_Embedded_Linked_201804] s
on  CAST(s.customer_cis as VARCHAR(500)) = CAST(k.dedupe_static as VARCHAR(500))
WHERE TRY_PARSE(s.customer_identifier as decimal(16,0)) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert(decimal(16,0), s.customer_identifier)

in both places you're referencing customer_identifier

This is assuming you don't have alpha characters in that column.

Comment: For the same reason I gave on a deleted answer, this won't work. Using `CONVERT` to try to force the conversion of an implicit conversion doesn't change the fact that the value can't be converted. The OP wouldn't be getting the error if they only had a numerical values. :)

Comment: Hence the "This is assuming you don't have alpha characters in that column" caveat, just trying to steer the OP in the right direction, technically the answer is still accurate

Comment: But that's my point; the OP is getting the error because they have non-numeric characters. If they didn't, the error would not be occurring.