# Error converting data type varchar to numeric on join clause

Tags: sql-server

Please help with this query.  I am getting an

> error converting data type varchar to numeric" on my join clause.

```
select 
       MARKETING
       ,HOME_TEL
       ,BUS_TEL 
       ,CEL_TEL 
       ,EMAIL   
       ,FAX 
       ,VALID_MAIL
       ,VALID_PHONE 
       ,VALID_SMS   
       ,VALID_EMAIL
       into [storagedb - baw].dbo.Geyser_Glynis
    from [storagedb - Mariana].dbo.HOC_Geyser_v2 as a
       left join [IIIDB].[dbo].[EEE_BASE_201901] as b
              on a.gcustomer_Number= b.Dedupe_Static
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You tried to join a numeric and a varchar column. The `varchar` columnd contained data that couldn't be converted to a number. Even if you add an explicit cast the query will be very slow because the server won't be able to use any of the indexes that cover the numeric or text column.

Comment: I *assume* `Dedupe_Static` isn't a `numeric`? Also, on a side note: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: share your database schema, for better calrification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error converting from varchar to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390199/error-converting-from-varchar-to-numeric)

Comment: Almost the exact same question from last year. <heavy sigh>

Answer (score 0):

Execute these 2 queries to find values that you are trying to join together that can't be cast to numeric:

```
SELECT
    T.gcustomer_Number
FROM
    [storagedb - Mariana].dbo.HOC_Geyser_v2 AS T
WHERE
    TRY_CAST(T.gcustomer_Number AS NUMERIC) IS NULL

SELECT
    T.Dedupe_Static
FROM
    [IIIDB].[dbo].[EEE_BASE_201901] AS T
WHERE
    TRY_CAST(T.Dedupe_Static AS NUMERIC) IS NULL
```

You will have to delete or update them to be able to be converted correctly to a number or, if one of the columns might hold non-numeric values, you will have to cast the numeric column to `VARCHAR`, for example:

```
from 
    [storagedb - Mariana].dbo.HOC_Geyser_v2 as a
    left join [IIIDB].[dbo].[EEE_BASE_201901] as b on 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), a.gcustomer_Number) = b.Dedupe_Static
```

Please note that applying conversion or functions against indexed columns will make the index inapplicable and most likely end in a full table scan.